# Converter data númerica no R

Tags: r, data.frame

Importei uma tabela JSON para o R e as datas estão no formato Unix.
Exemplo:

```
data <- c(1436904192, 1490717463, 1491924165)
```

Como posso converter toda essa coluna de uma única vez para o formato de data
`14/7/15 20:03`?

Answer (score 4):

Basta definir a origem da escala que a função `as.POSIXct` pode fazer a conversão.

```
data <- c(1436904192, 1490717463, 1491924165)

as.POSIXct(data, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2015-07-14 17:03:12 BRT" "2017-03-28 13:11:03 BRT" "2017-04-11 12:22:45 BRT"

format(as.POSIXct(data, origin="1970-01-01"), "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "14/07/15 17:03:12" "28/03/17 13:11:03" "11/04/17 12:22:45"
```

Observe que estou utilizando a timezone BRT (Brasil), padrão do meu sistema operacional. E no período de horário de verão, a timezone muda de BRT para BRST. Caso precise, pode definir qual a timezone deseja.

```
as.POSIXct(data, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT") 

[1] "2015-07-14 20:03:12 GMT" "2017-03-28 16:11:03 GMT" "2017-04-11 15:22:45 GMT"
```